# User Alerts Malfunctioning on only one Site Collection

Tags: 2010, site-collection, alert

There's an issue with user alerts not functioning in one site collection (on SharePoint 2010).  Apparently, the alerts were working and somewhere down the line they stopped.  I couldn't find out exactly when this issue started occuring.

When creating an alert (on a list/library/etc), an e-mail does get sent, however, there are not any other alert e-mails.  I've created workflows which send an e-mail and these work fine.

I've checked the timer jobs and there are not any issues with the timer jobs, according to Central Administration.

Comment: Does the Eventlog give us some information?

Comment: What kind of E-Mail infrasturcture do you use? Exchange? local SMTP?

Comment: And: Did you restore the DB that hosts the site collection from another server?

Comment: I checked the Eventlog and I don't see any new errors/warnings for the last few months.  Exchange is being used for e-mail.  And the DB was not restored, it was a new install of SharePoint 2010 so the DB was created new.

Alerts are functioning fine in the other site collections that reside in the same web application.  I was thinking of maybe trying the recommendation from the following URL about using stsadm, but I it seems that this recommendation might be for 2007.  [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepointadmin/thread/895a5612-9237-4d66-8cb3-37e7eefe8dbb)

Comment: Has this problem any solution please? Im facing it right now, just only one SC from 16 others stop sending e-mails with changes. First informational e-mail was sent, but nothing else. No issues in logs, no error message, any stsadm alerts-enabled & job-immediate-alerts commands did not helped us, all users has at least read permissions (contribute in most cases), no new features / solutions / workflows was made, there is no exchange filters or changes.... and still no e-mail alerts with any type of change

Comment: Could you maybe run this command in Powershell:

    $site = get-spsite http://yoursite.com;
    $site.alerts[0] | select *;

...and post the properties here? I'm guessing there's some issue with the configuration of the alerts but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Alerts are sent by timerjob "Immediate Alerts".

If you have multiple servers SharePoint farm, check that all servers that have service "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" enabled have permission to sent messages via smtp. You can use telnet to check.

"Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service should be enabled only on WFE servers.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to two different question. Either the questions are the same, and should be merged, or they are different and should have different answers. This answer is the exact same answer as [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178695/alert-not-working-for-single-site-collection/255121#255121)

Comment: Ok. I think the questions is the same.I just want to help. I spent much time to resolve this issue on my infrastructure.